# How to wait until specified keys will be pressed in NASM?

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, bootloader, bios

I'm creating custom MBR, that will load my message and after I press specified keys `CTRL+ALT+ESC` it will load original MBR, I have everything done except waiting for keys. I have found code that waits for *any* keypress, but I have specified keys, I know that I can use **AL** to set ASCII character of the button pressed, but I have 3 key combinations and also they are not ASCII character. So how can I realize this?

Here is part of my code, this is just example:

```
org 0x7c00
bits 16

    ; wait for key
    mov ah,0
    int 16h

    ; reboot
    int 19h


MBR_signature:
times 510-($-$$) db 0 
db 55h,0aah
```

Comment: okay, I found something out, but so far I don't know how to wait for ESC key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Int 16/AH=00h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1754.htm) to wait for the next keystroke. You can continue checking for keystrokes until <kbd>ESCAPE</kbd> is pressed. The [scan code](http://www.ee.bgu.ac.il/~microlab/MicroLab/Labs/ScanCodes.htm) for <kbd>ESCAPE</kbd> is 01h. If it has been pressed then you can use [Int 16/AH=02h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1756.htm) to get the shift flags which include whether <kbd>CONTROL</kbd> and/or <kbd>ALT</kbd> are currently pressed. Bits 2 and 3 of *AL* will contain their current state. This code snippet should demonstrate detection of <kbd>CONTROL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>ESCAPE</kbd>:

```
org 0x7c00
bits 16

getkey:
    xor ah,ah          ; AH = 0
    int 16h            ; Wait for key
    cmp ah, 01h        ; Scan code 1 = Escape
    jne getkey         ; If Escape not pressed get another key

    mov ah,2h
    int 16h            ; Query keyboard status flags
    and al, 0b00001111 ; Mask all the key press flags
    cmp al, 0b00001100 ; Check if ONLY Control and Alt are pressed and make sure
                       ;    Left and/or Right Shift are not being pressed
    jne getkey         ; If not go back and wait for another keystroke
                       ;    Otherwise Control-Alt-Escape has been pressed
    ; reboot
    int 19h

MBR_signature:
times 510-($-$$) db 0
db 55h,0aah
```